# Is there a command in Windbg which prints MINIDUMP_MISC_INFO_N from the Windows mini dumps?

Tags: windows, windbg

There's time zone information in windows dumps stored in MINIDUMP_MISC_INFO_N, yet I couldn't find the command which prints this information in windbg. So, I have to extract this information from the dump manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command `.timezone` which prints the timezone StandardName

```
:\>tzutil /s "Greenwich Standard Time"

:\>cdb -c ".timezone;q" calc.exe | grep -B 1 -A 1 Green
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.timezone;q'
Time zone: Greenwich Standard Time; (UTC - 00:00)
quit:

:\>tzutil /s "Tokyo Standard Time"

:\>cdb -c ".timezone;q" calc.exe | grep -B 1 -A 1 Tokyo
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.timezone;q'
Time zone: Tokyo Standard Time; (UTC + 09:00)
quit:

:\>tzutil /s "India Standard Time"

:\>cdb -c ".timezone;q" calc.exe | grep -B 1 -A 1 India
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.timezone;q'
Time zone: India Standard Time; (UTC + 05:30)
quit:
```

if you want something else from the misc structure you can code some thing along this line and retrieve all information

```
#include <engextcpp.hpp>
#include <dbghelp.h>
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension {
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(tzinfo);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(tzinfo,"Output TimeZoneInfo","{;e,o,d=0;tzinfo;Print TimeZone}")
{
    Out("outputs timezone info \n");
    MINIDUMP_MISC_INFO_N Info;
    HRESULT Status;
    if ((Status = m_Advanced2->Request(DEBUG_REQUEST_MISC_INFORMATION,NULL,
                    0,&Info,sizeof(Info),NULL)) == S_OK){
        Out("we recieved tzinfo %x\n %S\n" , Info.TimeZoneId , Info.TimeZone.StandardName);
    } else {
        Out("we didnot recieve tzinfo\n");
    }    
}
```

and use it like this

```
:\>.\cdb -c ".load tzinfo ;!tzinfo;q" calc | grep -A 4 Reading
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.load tzinfo ;!tzinfo;q'
outputs timezone info
we recieved tzinfo 0
 India Standard Time
quit:

:\>tzutil /s "Tokyo Standard Time"

:\>.\cdb -c ".load tzinfo ;!tzinfo;q" calc | grep -A 4 Reading
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.load tzinfo ;!tzinfo;q'
outputs timezone info
we recieved tzinfo 0
 Tokyo Standard Time
quit:
```